# Using named "Chart Data Ranges"

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, named-ranges

I am trying to build a chart which dynamically updates the series' selected based on user-defined selections from a drop-down menu.

Purpose is to create chart which displays n-series of data based on n-selections, e.g.

`=Output!$P$36:OFFSET(Output!$O$35,IF(Output!$C$4="RANK",COUNT(Output!$S$34:$S$38),COUNT(Output!$S$34:$S$38)+3),COUNTA(Output!$P$35:$W$35))`

The named range dynamically updates the chart area (i.e. row labels, column labels and data range). I reference it correctly i.e. as `='filename.xlsm'!named_range_here` in the "Chart Data Range" section.

1. When I do this, the Chart Data Range resets itself [help]
2. How can I tell excel to stop showing blank series (e.g. 2 blank series of 5 when i want it to display the 3 series which have values) [ideas please]

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a Name to the entire chart source data range, it is converted into its address. To keep dynamic Names, you need to define a Name for each distinct X and Y value range, and insert these into the respective series formulas.

If you're not shy about VBA, you can still make it work, following the approach in my tutorial [Dynamic Chart Source Data](http://peltiertech.com/dynamic-chart-source-data/).